# Chrome (And Torch) HTML not encoded or decoded properly

Tags: html, google-chrome, encoding, chromium, decoding

Quickly, before I begin, Torch is a chromium browser which I use on my desktop PC. I use Chrome on my Macbook Pro 13 inch (256gb one, probably not important), and I get the same issue, which is, in my opinion, *really* weird given that they're completely separate apart from each other except for how they're both logged into the same account.

So, onto the problem at hand. On some random websites, most notably a Chrome extension called Audio EQ, as well as some local sites such as chrome:// and torch:// depending on what browser I'm using, I get a random string of Chinese characters. It can be translated but it never means anything, so I figured that it's an encoding/decoding error due to the random nature of the text.

The text that's displayed in Audio EQ is this:

http://pastebin.com/RY4048QU

As you can probably tell, this is broken.

I ran it through a batch decoder/encoder website thing, and encoding to UTF-16 resulted in something that looks a little bit more like HTML.

(I would post a link here to it but I don't have 10 reputation, so check the replies to this post below for the link)

It's HTML. Sort of. The text is backwards and the syntax is a little bit off but it at least looks like HTML now.

So what's going on here? How come it happens on both my Mac and my PC even though they're mostly separate (And if it's because they're using the same Google account, how does this affect how encoding/decoding happens?)? Most importantly, how should I go about fixing this?

Thanks for any replies, and sorry for including a lot of text, although this is a more complex issue than I'm used to asking about.

Comment: Macbook Pro Retina 13 inch... probably not important but I forgot the Retina bit...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qrfAUYkN is the link to the encoded Chinese stuff which looks somewhat like HTML even though it's really not.